# create circular Auto Horizontal Scroll View?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I implement circular Auto Horizontal Scroll using HorizontalScollView.

**What I did:** I added child linear layout, which contain initial default child view let's say 10.

```
private void startScrolling() {

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                counter = (int) (counter + 10);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);

                    viewCount++;

                    if(viewCount == MAX_CHILD) {
                        viewCount = 0;
                        resetViewPosition(0);
                    }

                    mScroller.scrollTo(counter , 0);
            }
        }, 1000L);
    }
```

Now once scrolling start it remove first index view, and add same element at last of view. view keep on scrolling because of timer using postDelay() implementation.

```
private void resetViewPosition(int viewIndex) {

        View view = llParent.getChildAt(viewIndex);

        Log.v(TAG, "resetViewPosition : "+view.getId()+", "+llParent.getChildCount());
        llParent.removeViewAt(viewIndex);
        llParent.addView(view);
    }
```

Issue: ScrollView stopped scrolling after scroll initial element lenth, i.e. it's not expanding with addition new child of linear layout.

Please suggest me what I can do here to implement same.

Comment: Following our chat discussion and for logging purposes : https://code.google.com/p/infinite-gallery/

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720469/horizontalscrollview-auto-scroll-to-end-when-new-views-are-added

Comment: thanks ..will try it..and since question asked long before so not sure where I need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gallery, i think it will work fine with your needs

Comment: gallery was an option to palce content horizontaly...but when u talk auto about scrolling...it give bad experience..i tried this before.